# Does BigQuery WRITE_TRUNCATE work when apache beam job is unbounded (Reading from Pub/Sub) and Write Method is FILE_LOADS

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to see if `BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE` works when `BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS` is used in an unbounded apache beam job.

Basically the beam job reads data from Pub/Sub and writes it to big query with the below configurations.

```
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
.withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
.withTriggeringFrequency(org.joda.time.Duration.standardDays(1))
```

The data gets loaded to BigQuery but the table doesn't get truncated.

I came across [this document](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.20.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) which says `For streaming pipelines WriteTruncate can not be used.`
But i'm not using `STREAMING_INSERTS` inserts and using `FILE_LOADS` instead and hence my assumption was that `WRITE_TRUNCATE` should work.

Comment: When you use `Pub/Sub` as an input, the pipeline will automatically be a `streaming pipeline`.

Comment: @CaptainNabla Looks like that's the case.